# URL pattern to include in JMeter for testing ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: url, asp.net-mvc-2, jmeter

I am trying to perform a load test with JMeter on my ASP.NET MVC website that I have published on IIS..

My problem is..I'm confused about what URL pattern should I include or exclude..Currently, URL is immaterial for me, so I tried with '.* ' in URL to include and nothing in URL to exclude.. But JMeter is recording only a jpg url...If I specify '.*\.jpg ' in exclude, it records nothing. I also tried '.*\.aspx ' in include and nothing in exclude, but that doesn't seem to be working either :(

Is this something MVC specific? I am not very sure how it handles urls..(I am doing all this for the first time..). I otherwise didn't have any issues recording steps on other servers like google,apache.jmeter.test etc. where there were normal html pages with my current JMeter settings:

A Thread Group called 'Users' having a 
Recording Controller 
HTTP request defaults pointing to localhost:9080

A Workbench with 
HTTP Proxy Server pointing to localhost:9080

My connection setting is also on localhost:9080.
I'm running JMeter from behind my company's proxy server successfully.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized later that it was not about URLs as such. My browser setting was probably faulty. I was using IE8..When I switched to Firefox, got more fine-grained control on the settings..These settings before recording worked for me:

Set manual proxy configuration to localhost,8081.
Check 'Use this proxy for all protocols'
Leave 'No proxy for' field blank
No 'Automatic proxy configuration'
Click OK.

After this if you try to access your site on IIS while JMeter proxy server hasn't started yet, it wouldn't, saying the connection was refused.

After this, go to JMeter and click the Start button to record. Try acessing the site again. It should come up :) Some more details:
There was no need to specify port number in HTTP request defaults. Just specified it in HTTP proxy server (8081 in my case).
For the session information to be saved properly, you must use a cookie manager (preferably, keep it at the top)..When you record, you get a HTTP header manager under each HTTP request if you had ticked the chekcbox against "Capture HTTP headers" in HTTP Proxy Server before recording..Copy this and add it as a child under your thread group.

Hope this helps someone struggling like me :)